# Null Hypothesis vs alternative hypothesis

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a question that I can't seem to get my head around. The company repeatedly claims that 80 % of their clients are satisfied with the product. Use an hypothesis test at the 5% level of significance to decide weather there is sufficient evidence to conclude that their claim is valid in May. I am not interested in getting an answer , that seems to be the easy bit. I am having trouble with the alternative hypothesis and null hypothesis.

I believe that the alternative hypothesis is what you are testing for. So in this case I thought it would be that the the company's the mean is 80%. But the answer is giving that null hypothesis is that the mean is 80%. Any comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to specify exactly what test you are using.  Different tests can have different direction (meaning for some tests the null hypothesis will be the equivalent of the alternative hypothesis for another test).

Comment: I wonder, if you posted a question with a title of just "Null Hypothesis", if the moderators would instinctively reject it.

Comment: @Owen: https://xkcd.com/892/